# How do I get TypeScript to ignore imports?

Tags: typescript, import

Let's say I have the following TypeScript file:

```
import { X, Y, Z } from "./abc";

console.log("Done!");
```

How do I get TypeScript to ignore the import statement (**I.E:** remove it) so the compiled result looks like this:

```
console.log("Done!");
```

Comment: This is not possible with typescript, it is not it's purpose. You can do it with some custom Babel plugin

Comment: I don't want to actually do it, I'm just wondering if it's possible.

Comment: It is not possible, the purpose of TS is to provide a types mechanism + support future syntax

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a **global.d.ts** and add

```
declare module '*';
```

It automatically makes all js modules any while ts modules keep working as intended.

Now you are free to import any js modules without typings!

Comment: I understand this is soo wrong but you're a LIFE SAVER!